# How do you make a switch case not occur more than once in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am making a multiplication quiz app that uses switches for various levels.

If I want only two questions to be asked in this switch, how can I make it so a case/question that has already been asked doesn't get asked twice?

```
    var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 4
    RandomNumber += 1

    switch(RandomNumber){

    case 1:

        QuestionLabel.text = "What is 4 x 2?"
        Button1.setTitle("2", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button2.setTitle("4", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button3.setTitle("8", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button4.setTitle("12", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        CorrectAnswer = "3"
        break

    case 2:

        QuestionLabel.text = "What is 3 x 3?"
        Button1.setTitle("6", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button2.setTitle("9", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button3.setTitle("12", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button4.setTitle("33", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        CorrectAnswer = "2"
        break

    case 3:

        QuestionLabel.text = "What is 3 x 2?"
        Button1.setTitle("6", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button2.setTitle("8", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button3.setTitle("9", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button4.setTitle("13", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        CorrectAnswer = "1"
        break

    case 4:

        QuestionLabel.text = "What is 4 x 3?"
        Button1.setTitle("8", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button2.setTitle("9", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button3.setTitle("11", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        Button4.setTitle("12", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        CorrectAnswer = "4"
        break

    default:
        break
    }
```

Comment: I think you should store your RandomNumber in an array. Then check it, if it doesn't in array -> call switch else call random function again.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon my massive refactoring, but it was fun to Swiftify this code :)

I made the following adjustments:

- Struct for questions, enum for right/wrong
- Array extension for removing a random element
- Use button tag to identify buttons with choices

```
struct Question {
    let title: String
    let choices: [Choice]

    enum Choice {
        case Right(String)
        case Wrong(String)

        var title: String {
            switch self {
            case let .Wrong(str): return str
            case let .Right(str): return str
            }
        }
    }
}

var unaskedQuestions = [
    Question(title: "What is 4 x 2?", choices:
        [.Wrong("2"), .Wrong("4"), .Right("8"), .Wrong("12")]),

    Question(title: "What is 3 x 3?", choices:
        [.Wrong("6"), .Right("9"), .Wrong("12"), .Wrong("33")]),

    Question(title: "What is 3 x 3?", choices:
        [.Wrong("6"), .Right("9"), .Wrong("12"), .Wrong("33")]),

    Question(title: "What is 4 x 3?", choices:
        [.Wrong("8"), .Wrong("9"), .Wrong("11"), .Right("12")])
]

// ...

extension Array {
    mutating func removeRandomElement() -> Element {
        let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
        return removeAtIndex(i)
    }
}

var currentQuestion = unaskedQuestions.removeRandomElement()

// ...

func displayQuestion(question: Question)
{
    questionLabel.text = question.title
    for (idx, (btn, choice)) in zip(buttons, question.choices).enumerate() {
        btn.tag = idx
        btn.setTitle(choice.title, forState: .Normal)
    }
}

// ...

func buttonTapped(button: UIButton)
{
    if case .Right = currentQuestion.choices[button.tag] {
        // Correct answer!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I want only two questions to be asked in this switch, how can I make it so a case/question that has already been asked doesn't get asked twice?

The naïve way is to use an array to store the numbers of all previously asked questions. But using a random number generator to come up with the next question number isn't such a great option. Consider what would happen if you have a total of 30 questions, and you've already asked 29 of them. You'd have an array with 29 numbers, so that only one valid number remains, and you'd have to keep picking random numbers until you hit on the last number not in the array.

So, a better solution is to make a list of all the question numbers, and then shuffle that list. Let's say you have 10 questions, so you start with an array like: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. Next, pick a number between 1 and 10 and swap the first item in the array with the item at that index. For example, if you pick 7, you'd swap the first element with the 7th element: `[7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 9, 10]`. Repeat for each position in the array, so that you end up with something like: `[3, 9, 1, 7, 10, 4, 2, 5, 6, 8]`. Now you have a random list of question numbers, and you ask the questions in the order given by the array. Each number appears only once, so you know you won't ask the same question more than once.